# Python tkinter multiple windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I can run both files separately. Main file is prj.py When I import cfg in prj.py to run cfg.py I get `NameError: name 'root' is not defined.` Trying to have option access cfg.py if necessary. If cfg.py necessary destroy prj.py continue/run cfg.py

**prj.py**

```py
import cfg
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.GetChk()        
    def GetChk(self):
        print ('PRJ')
        opn_cfg = tk.Button(root, text='CFG', width=10, command=self.GetCfg)
        opn_cfg.place(x=50, y=50)
    def GetCfg(self):
        print ('prj')
        root.destroy()
        cfg.Configuration()

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('PRJ')
    root.geometry('500x250')
    root.resizable(0,0)
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**cfg.py**

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Configuration(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        #self.root = tk.Tk()
        #self.root.title('CFG')
        #self.root.geometry('250x125')
        #self.root.resizable(0,0)
        self.GetChk()
    def GetChk(self):
        print('CFG')      #(self.root, text='OUT', width=10, command=self.GetPrj)
        opn_prj = tk.Button(root, text='OUT', width=10, command=self.GetPrj)
        opn_prj.place(x=50, y=50)
    def GetPrj(self):
        print('cfg')

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    root = tk.Tk()              #comment out if in init
    root.title('CFG')           #comment out if in init       
    root.geometry('250x125')    #comment out if in init
    root.resizable(0,0)         #comment out if in init
    app = Configuration(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you want to display two windows then second window should be `tk.Toplevel` - `tkinter` should run only one window `tk.Tk()` and one `mainloop()`. And you should send it as argument to class - `Configure(second_window)` and keep it as ie. `self.window` and use  `Button(self.window,...)`

Comment: BTW: you have to remeber that code in `if __name__ == "__main__": ` in `cfg.py` is not executed when you import `cfg.py` - so it will not create secodn `tk.Tk()`, not set title and geometry. You have to on create second window on your own. You could set title and geometry inside `__init__`

Comment: now I see your main problem is that `import` never execute code in `if __name__ == "__main__": `  - it is standard behavior. You have to put code from `if __name__ == "__main__": ` in some function - ie. `create_window()` - and in second file run `cfg.create_window()`

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

is special construction to execute some code only when you run script directly but now when you import it.

And this is your main problem. You have to put this code in function which you can execute manually in second script - `cfg.create_window()`

But it makes other problem. Now `root` is local variable so it is not accesible inside class and you can't use it in `Button()`. But you put `root` as argument `app = Configuration(root)` so if you use

```
tk.Frame().__init__(super, *args, **kwargs)
```

or shorter (ad preferred in Python 3)

```
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

then `Frame` will get `root` and assign to `self.master` and you can use `self.master` in `Button`

**cfg.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

class Configuration(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.get_chk()

    def get_chk(self):
        print('CFG')
        opn_prj = tk.Button(self.master, text='OUT', width=10, command=self.get_prj)
        opn_prj.place(x=50, y=50)

    def get_prj(self):
        print('cfg')

def create_window():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('CFG')
    root.geometry('250x125')
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    app = Configuration(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    create_window()
```

**prj.py**

```
import cfg
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.get_chk()

    def get_chk(self):
        print ('PRJ')
        opn_cfg = tk.Button(self.master, text='CFG', width=10, command=self.get_cfg)
        opn_cfg.place(x=50, y=50)

    def get_cfg(self):
        print ('prj')
        self.master.destroy()
        cfg.create_window()

def create_window():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('PRJ')
    root.geometry('500x250')
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    create_window()
```

---

**BTW:** I changed function names to `lower_case_names` base on [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

**BTW:** If you plan to destroy `Configuration` and create again `Application` then you will have big problem to do it - so it is not good idea. You should rather replace content in one window. Or create Configuration as `Toplevel` and hide `Application` instead of destroying it.

Comment: Super thanks. As you were posting your first actually editing as per your 'first push proper direction'. I have updated the question to reflect editing. It works however you get PRJ window + CFG window and extra Tk window. Then I thought of raise SystemExit sys.exit() that is another can of worms. I cannot believe closing one file opening another is this great endeavor. Seriously furas cheers!